# select first empty form field

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

I'm checkin a form for empty values via the following method

```
      $("#reservationForm").find("input[type=email], input[type=tel], input[type=text]").filter(function(){
       if($(this).val() == ""){
        $(this).css("border","solid 1px red").after('Please fill in your '+this.id+'');
        f.preventDefault();
       }
```

Now i want to improve the usability and set the focus to the first empty field, but that's the problem. I tried all of the following, but everytime only the *last* empty field gets the focus

```
        $(this).eq(0).focus();
        $(this:first).focus();
        $(this:first-child).focus();
```

How can i set the focus automatically to the *first* empty field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place it at the end, after the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) overall, like this:

```
$("#reservationForm").find("input[type=email], input[type=tel], input[type=text]").filter(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ""){
     $(this).css("border","solid 1px red").after('Please fill in your '+this.id+'');
     f.preventDefault();
     return true;
  }
}).first().focus();
```

This way you're getting the [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) of the elements that match the filter.  The `return true` is important because only those elements that *are* empty are left in the set after the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is called...currently you're using it as more of a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) call.

The reason it's currently setting it to the last is `this` is *each element* as you iterate through, so it's focusing all of them, and whichever runs *last* is the one left with the focus...instead you want to get the set of empty and focus the first of *those* elements.

Comment: What does the 'f' stands for in : f.preventDefault(); ??

Comment: @MilchePatern - Likely from an outer event handler now shown in the question (this being a subset of the code).  It would be the event passed into the handler, for example `.click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just couldn't figure out where the 'f' came from since : 'filter(function(){' has no event handler ticker. ;)